# How to fetch an associated-through collection (proxied collection) using active-record methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have a `has_many` relation between `Subscription` and `Article`, an article has a `Product`.

```
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :articles
end

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :subscription
  belongs_to :product
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subscriptions
end
```

Now. I'd like to simply fetch all products from within my subscriptions.

Solution `includes`:

```
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :articles
  def products
    articles.includes(:product).map{|a| ap.product} # Or .map(&:product)
  end
end
```

Solution `has_many :through`:

```
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :articles
  has_many :products, through: articles
end
```

The first has the downside that it does not return a collection that can be chained upon (e.g. `subscription.products.pluck(:id)`), but rather a simple array.

The second is not entirely 'semantically' correct: I don't want it to become a full-blown association, but simply a helper to fetch a list.

Am I simply overlooking some activerecord method that allows me to fetch the associated-through items?

Comment: Could you clarify why you don't want this to be "has_many through"? It appears from the outside here to be the ideal solution.

Comment: `bar has_many :foo, through: :baz` does a lot more than just allowing me to fetch `self.baz.foo`: it adds a lot of methods and stuff to my public interface. Moreover, it communicates to the outside world that there is a coupling between self, foo and bar. And worse, it is a leaky abstraction: suddenly my `bar` knows about how `baz` and `foo` are coupled. Whereas in clean OOP i'd not be interested in that at all: only in that I send `foo` to my `baz`; nothing more.

Comment: Ah yes, this is all true. To quote Joel, "all non-trivial abstractions, to some degree, are leaky". ActiveRecord is a both a convenience and a compromise. With Rails in general, we can spend time fighting the conventions of the framework and working harder to enforce additional conventions on top of what's provided or we can do the easy thing. In some cases, I find many of these concerns don't really matter, but that's all perspective.

Comment: You are entirely correct, @rossta, yet the code above already is a very much simplified version of reality. What I am trying to solve is a spagetti of `has_many :foo, through :bar` that appear in nearly every model associating nearly every other model in our current application. In other words: currently a large part of our models is connected to all other models in the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would typically write this as a "has_many through" so the returned `products` will behave like a relation. To achieve something similar in a `Subscription` method, you could add the missing `has_many` association to `Product` and merge subscription articles on a `Product` join:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :articles
end

class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :articles

  def products
    Product.joins(:articles).merge(articles)
  end
end
```

In this case, `Subscription#products` will return an `ActiveRecord` collection.

Comment: I guess, this is the key here: "add the missing has_many association to `Product`"

Comment: I am not completely sure what the `has_many :articles` in `Product` really means, here. It sounds like it is used as a private helper to allow creating nicer joins; but in reality I am adding stuff to the public API of Product. Or am I missing a key point?

Comment: Without context, I don't know what `has_many :articles` for `Product` really means for your domain. On the most basic level, it simply reflects the inverse of `Article` `belongs_to` `:product`. You're correct, it does add to the public api of Product, which includes the ability to do joins like I've shown. Otherwise, you need to drop down to SQL in your products method or roll your own notion of keeping these relationships private. To get the convenience offered through Rails, product does need to "know" about articles.